# Unable to create calendar link in HTML

Tags: php, html, calendar

All,

I am using the calendar PHP source code at [this link](http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php) in my HTML page, but I am not able to get the calendar. My page simply displays the source code (which might mean I have not linked it properly). Here is the my HTML code:

```
<?php
   require_once('/calendar/classes/tc_calendar.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
<title> Welcome </title>
<script language="javascript" src="calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<link href="calendar/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
....
Date: 
<?php
      $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date5", true, false);
      $myCalendar->setIcon("/calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
      $myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));
      $myCalendar->setPath("/calendar/");
      $myCalendar->setYearInterval(2000, 2015);
      $myCalendar->dateAllow('2008-05-13', '2015-03-01');
      $myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');
      $myCalendar->writeScript();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it the file path that might be a problem? I am on Windows platform and I have tried changing the complete path to `C:\\calendar\\classes\tc_calendar.php` and it still does not work.

The HTML pages show all the fields before the `Date` field. I have the source code displayed for the `Date` field and not the actual calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the form shows up right *before* the calendar but it is blank after? I don't see anything obviously wrong in your PHP code so it must be an error in tc_calendar.php. Add `error_reporting(-1);` to show all messages and `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` to the very top of your script to see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your PHP file as ANSI instead of Unicode. I had the same problem, and for now this seems to be the only solution for the calendar to show up in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more futureproof solution: simply use [the HTML5 `date` input type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html)

### Example for you

---

```
<input type="date" id="date5" min="2008-05-13" max="2015-03-01"/>
```

That's 10 lines of code in 1! Of course, you should keep your current solution as a backup in case the user is using Firefox≤17 or IE≤10, as those don't support the date input, yet.